# How can I verify firebase on iOS using Unity?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, verify

I need to add firebase to an iOS app, I download the SDK and add the googleservice-info.plist in my asset folder.
The Unity firebase window shows that firebase is enabled but when I compile and run tha app the Firebase SDK setup doesn't finish and isn't tracking any events.

With Android I don't have any problems

I use Unity 2018.2

Greetings

[verify firebase IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC6gG.png)

Comment: This is a really broad question as the issue could be caused by 100 different things. What does *Firebase SDK setup doesn't finish* mean? Does it present an error? Does it crash? Does it display a blank screen? Remember we can only work with the info you provide so your descriptions needs to be brief but complete. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
We already fix it, the solutions was restoring the mac (it has an old hard drive so we update it  with a new SSD).